# Can I use WiFi to receive video/audio sign and mobile data to connect to the internet at the same time?

Tags: wifi, iot

I have a question about an IoT device. Can I connect my IoT device to a mobile phone using WIFI and then connect the mobile phone with the internet through 4G mobile data? My IoT device will send video and audio signals to the phone, and an app will communicate with the internet using 4G mobile data. Therefore, effectively the IoT device is communicating with the internet through the mobile app. In the communication between the IoT device and the mobile phone. The IoT device acts as a WIFI hotspot so the mobile phone can connect to it.

Comment: If I understand it right, you just try to use your mobile phone as hotspot to connect the IoT device to the internet, or did I get this wrong? Maybe you can describe a bit clearer what your question is?

Comment: If I understand the communication path is IOT device > Mobile Phone > Cellular tower > Internet. If so this method is very common. For example if you take the configuration process for a WEMO device the initial setup process can and most times use the part you described.

Comment: Isn't this the basis of IOT?  IOT using Wifi to connect to Mobile Phone Hotspot using mobile data to connect to internet.

Comment: @OpticalResonator  Thank you all for your answers. Actually, in my case, it is the IoT device itself that acts as a WiFi hotspot and the smartphone is connecting to it. Therefore, I got a problem that the smartphone cannot get access to the internet when it's connecting to the IoT device.